# HWND differs if a tooltip shown

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, browser, ui-automation

I dealing with a function which retrieves url from current browser. It is working until a tooltip appears. (See example)

[image]

So far, I managed to find it out that the tooltip has different `HWND`. The tooltip is the top window on it's own `UiAutomationTree` and it's not part of the browser.

The question is: How to find the browser window related to the tooltip?

The issue appears while using ie, firefox or chrome. (I did not tested other browsers)

### UPDATE:

I forgot to mention that I got the HWND from `GetActiveWindow` and when the tooltip appears `GetActiveWindow` returns tooltip's HWND.

Comment: Have you checked the tooltip window's parent? [GetWindowLong(GWL_HWNDPARENT)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633584(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: I will try it on monday. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Process p = Process.GetProcessByName(browserProcessName);
IntPtr hwnd = p.MainWindowHandle;
```

Comment: You're not really answering the question, which is likely why someone flagged you. OP wants to somehow do this through using the ToolTip (which may not even be possible). This is a good answer in general, I think, for getting the hwnd, though.

Comment: He said it works fine UNLESS there is a tool tip. This will work with a tool tip.

Comment: `GetProcessesByName` returns with an Array of `Process`. Based on the tooltip window how I can find out which process is the current (active) browser window? (By the way the array will contains the tooltip's process too)

Comment: you are getting more than one Process object back when you give it "firefox" or "firefox.exe"? Or whatever browser you are using